# access 2007: how to have multiple user logins that can only view certain tables?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've already created a **Welcome page** where a user chooses amongst **3 user types (buttons)**. Each button takes the user to **their own login forms**. After they login they are each taken to **their own switchboard.**

The **problem** is they can still see the options on the left. I "unchecked" the option in options menu, but they can just check those if they wanted to, to see them.

I want some users to be locked out from accessing those navigation options permanently **because there's sensitive information in some of the tables.**

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accomplish your objective using just Access then you'll need to store the tables in an `.mdb` file and configure it to use [*user-level security*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/about-user-level-security-mdb-HP003070410.aspx). However, that approach has at least two significant disadvantages:

1. User-level security can be a nuisance to set up and maintain, and
2. That security model (encrypted .mdb files and associated .mdw "workgroup" files) is [deprecated](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/what-happened-to-user-level-security-HA010342116.aspx).

If you're serious about your security requirements then you'd be better off using something like Microsoft SQL Server (perhaps the Express Edition) for your back-end data store.